# How to get group managed service accounts using UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity?

Tags: c#, .net

I have one gMSA user created. I am trying to get the user sid-

```
ContextType contextType= ContextType.Domain;

PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(contextType, domain);

using (var foundUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName))
            {
                if (foundUser != null)
                {
                    identity = foundUser.Sid.Value;
                    result = true;
                }
            }
```

The gMSA user is under a domain such as contoso.ab.cd.com

Comment: Is context pointing at the right domain? Do you have more than one domain in your environment?

Comment: The context is pointing to right domain. Yes I have more than one domain

Comment: And where is your problem? Give us more information, some error msg or something. What are you using to log that user on active directory? Also check `IdentityType`, I don't have information what is your userName here. 
`IdentityType.Name` - is the name of the account
`IdentityType.SamAccountName` - is the username.

Comment: There is no error message but the UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity returns nothing. gmsatest$ is the SamAccountName.

Comment: Ok but what is your userName here? Try to debug that, look what are u getting in IdentityType, check context too. If you are using email maybe, check https://doogalbellend.blogspot.com/2012/03/finding-userprincipal-for-email-address.html

Answer (score 2):

I ran in to this issue as well.  In my environment, I noticed that the gMSA accounts are not in the UserPrincipal at all.  Rather, they are in ComputerPrincipal.  Try the following:

```
ContextType contextType= ContextType.Domain;

PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(contextType, domain);

using (var foundUser = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName))
            {
                if (foundUser != null)
                {
                    identity = foundUser.Sid.Value;
                    result = true;
                }
            }
```